# Are some these indexes redundant?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table of 4 columns: A, B, C, D. A primary key is on A, B, C.

Index1: is A, D, B, C in that order
Index2: A, B, C, D in that order
and the primary key index: A, B, C

There are queries selecting different columns in different numbers and order. I don't all the queries that hit the table.

Are some indexes here redundant?

I collected some scripts from the web for finding redundant indexes and they don't return the same results for the database. I guess every author has their own interpretation of what constitutes a duplicate or redundant index.

Comment: If the primary key is clustered, then A, B, C, D is redundant. Column order in select does not matter for index usage.

Comment: A, D, B, C sounds quite useless too, if D is really selective, it should be the first column, otherwise no need for the whole index because clustered index should cover it

Comment: You should check "Index Usage Statistics" report in SSMS (when right clicking the database). It will tell you how many times the indexes have been used and updated.

Comment: Everything of course depends on the update/insert vs read - ratio on the table. Having redundant indexes on tables that aren't updated that often isn't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

If the PK is A,B,C, you already have that unique index.

A,B,C,D is a covering index for queries that need exactly those four columns, but would be better as A,B,C INCLUDE D

A,D,B,C is definitely not redundant; it's the only one that can work with both A and D on queries that use those two but don't use B or C in the index.  Depending on the cardinality of A and D, it might be critical, or worthless... but it's not redudant.

Remember, SQL Server starts at the left and goes to the right; when it hits a column that's not used, it stops.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are technically redundant only if they are identical in all respects: clustered/non-clustered, key list, column order, sequence specification, included columns, filtering specification.  Even slight variations may result in one index being more beneficial to a query than another similar one.  Examine `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` over time to identify which indexes may not be needed.

There are often trade-offs involved.  It may be appropriate to compromise with fewer indexes rather than create the perfect index for every query.  Keep those that are most useful to high-volume/expensive/critical queries.